# Implement a service to stay alive permanently for detecting BLE controllers on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service, android-doze

I have an access system based on BLE controllers and a cloud service. We're going to implement the "hands-free" mode for getting access to the restricted area. It means:

- user don't need to get a smartphone to enable the access (it should work the whole work day)
- the smartphone should scan/find BLE controllers in the background mode.

My thoughts:

Plan 'A' is using a combination of

1. Foreground service (working in the active mode)
2. FCM high-priority messaging (waking up in the [Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby))

Plan 'B' is using the white-list apps of Android to prevent battery optimisation in the Doze mode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the app to stay alive if you just want to perform a background BLE scan. Just use the PendingIntent BLE scan feature https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent). Then your app process will be started when an advertisement packet matching your filter arrives.